# CS0433 Monogame and Xna

Tags: visual-studio, xna, monogame, xna-4.0

Added Xna.Framework.Storage but got error:

Error CS0433 The type "Matrix" exists in both "Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 842cf8be1de50553" and "MonoGame.Framework, Version = 3.8.0.1641, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null ".

Tried giving paths: Monogame.Framework Matrix. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not attempt to load both XNA and MonoGame in your references.

Pick one.

MonoGame is better for cross platform.....

Answer (score 0):

It is ***not*** possible to use both XNA and MonoGame references. If you have an actual reason to use Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage then you can only reference XNA, since MonoGame has removed the Storage namespace.

Or, you could use FNA which has high compatibility with XNA stuff so I'd suggest that instead